# How to create and parse Tag, Length, Value (TLV) in JavaScript or java and encode it in Base64

Tags: javascript, java, base64, encode, tlv

The QR code fields shall be encoded in Tag-Length-Value (TLV) format with the tag values specified in the “Tag” column of the adjacent table in the image below.

The TLV encoding shall be as follows:

Tag: the tag value as mentioned above is stored in one byte
Length: the length of the byte array resulted from the UTF8 encoding of the field value. The length shall be stored in one byte.
Value: the byte array resulting from the UTF8 encoding of the field value.

This image describe my problem:

[image]

Comment: We don't need that image as long as you describe things well enough in your post. On that note: look at your post after you submit it because it needs to follow [the posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask), and definitely needs to use [the correct formatting](/markdown). With that said: what's your actual problem? Nothing in your post talks about what you've written so far, and where you got stuck in that process, so there isn't anything [for SO to help you with](/help/on-topic) yet?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the required hashes by using this library [here](https://github.com/busaeed/E-InvoiceQRBarcode).

```
String qrBarcodeHash = QRBarcodeEncoder.encode(
    new Seller("شركة تجريبية"),
    new TaxNumber("312345678901233"),
    new InvoiceDate("2021-11-18T18:40:34+03:00"),
    new InvoiceTotalAmount("2.30"),
    new InvoiceTaxAmount("0.30")
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Bu Saeed